# NullPointerException in add() Method

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, addition

My problem is I created an `add()` method for my `ArrayList`.

I get an `NullPointerException`. How can I implement an `add()` method in my class as the following code suggests?

here is the code:

```
public class XY{

    private List<DictEntry> dict = new ArrayList<DictEntry>();

    public void add(String word, int frequency) {
        DictEntry neu = new DictEntry(word, frequency);
        if (word == null || frequency == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (!dict.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dict.size(); i++) {
                if (dict.get(i).getWord() == word) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        dict.add(neu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the stack trace of the exception. Tell us which line it refers to. And don't use == to compare Strings but `equals()`.

Comment: `if (dict.get(i).getWord() == word) {` should use `.equals(word)` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `null` element in your array. `dict.get(i).getWord()` is like `null.getWord()`

Answer (score 0):

Without the line number it's thrown on, it's harder to say.  But I'd suggest not taking the approach you are, anyhow.

First off: don't reimplement functionality that exists:

```
public class XY{
private List<DictEntry> dict = new ArrayList<DictEntry>();


    public void add(String word, int frequency) {
       if (word == null || frequency == 0) {
            return;
        }

       DictEntry neu = new DictEntry(word, frequency);
       if (!dict.contains(word)) {
         dict.add(word);
       }
    }
}
```

Even better, use a structure more appropriate to the problem. You're mapping a word to a count - that's all that you appear to be doing with the DictEntry, here.  So why not:

```
public class XY{
private Map<String, Integer> dict = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void add(String word, int frequency) {
       dict.put(word, frequency);
}
```